# Do you need client-side script for a server to access local storage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want my page to use local storage, for users to store customer names to be retrieved later.
I need to reassure users that my site (server) will not access the local storage.

Do I understand this correctly? For the server to access local storage, it **has** to use a client-side script (e.g. JavaScript) to get at it. This script would be apparent if the client-side source code was examined (e.g. using view:source).
So the reassurance would be testable.
Or can the server access local storage without there being anything visible client-side?

Comment: You already mentioned server and client. Hence you should understand server side can only access to data that are being fed to it by external sources. In this case, your client side scripts.

Comment: I'm with @SomeoneSpecial It's called *LocalStorage* for a reason - If you want shared storage, look into cookies

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Just wanted to be sure there was no way of quietly feeding it back through the headers or anything else, like cookies.

Answer (score 1):

one computer cant access other computer's local storage. Even both computer online sametime. there must be serverside script to transfer data each other.